# PHP and ordering array items with numbers and texts

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using PHP. I have an array which has 1-256 items. Here is an example:

```
$arr[] = "(1.) Ben";
$arr[] = "Albert";
$arr[] = "Bill";
$arr[] = "(2.) Paul";
$arr[] = "(5.) Martin";
$arr[] = "(12.) Mike";
$arr[] = "(20.) John";
```

**Question 1:**

I would like to order the items alphabetically by names. So, the result should be this:

```
Albert
(1.) Ben
Bill
(20.) John
(5.) Martin
(12.) Mike
(2.) Paul
```

**Question 2:**

I also would like to order the items by 1) numbers and 2) names like this way:

```
(1.) Ben
(2.) Paul
(5.) Martin
(12.) Mike
(20.) John
Albert
Bill
```

How could I do the job with PHP?

Comment: Try using `usort()` it allows you to supply a function to sort your array

Comment: php got sort functions: `asort()` for sorting by value and `ksort()` for sorting by key

Comment: Maybe my question was bad. I have modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sorting for `Question 1`:

```
<?php

$arr[] = "(1.) Ben";
$arr[] = "Albert";
$arr[] = "Bill";
$arr[] = "(2.) Paul";
$arr[] = "(5.) Martin";
$arr[] = "(12.) Mike";
$arr[] = "(20.) John";

usort($arr, function($a, $b){
    $a = explode(' ', $a, 2);
    $a = (count($a) > 1) ? $a[1] : $a[0];

    $b = explode(' ', $b, 2);
    $b = (count($b) > 1) ? $b[1] : $b[0];

    return strcmp($a, $b);
});

print_r($arr); //  // Print array sorted for 'Question 1'
```

**@EDIT**
And sorting for `Question 2`:

```
$arr[] = "(1.) Ben";
$arr[] = "Albert";
$arr[] = "Bill";
$arr[] = "(2.) Paul";
$arr[] = "(5.) Martin";
$arr[] = "(12.) Mike";
$arr[] = "(20.) John";

usort($arr, function($a, $b){
    $a = explode(' ', $a, 2);
    $b = explode(' ', $b, 2);

    if(count($a) > 1 && count($b) > 1)
    {
        $a = str_replace(['(', ')', '.'], '', $a[0]);
        $b = str_replace(['(', ')', '.'], '', $b[0]);

        return $a > $b;
    }
    else
    {
        return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
    }
});

print_r($arr); // Print array sorted for 'Question 2'
```

Comment: How about sorting for question 2 if there are "(1.) Ben Hall" and "Albert Newson"?

Answer (score 0):

php got sort functions: asort() for sorting by value and ksort() for sorting by key.

```
asort($arr); // now sorted by value.
ksort($arr); // now sorted by key.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using index array so u can sort alphabetically by asort() function but for the  another questions u have to make a function ie. The order in which u want to sort  and then apply uasort() function. Link is  php.net/manual/en/functions.uasort.php check the above link u might get clear